# How to implement google maps with best possible backward compatibility in an android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, compatibility

I'm building a simple android app that uses Google maps api to display map and navigation. As you may know Google maps need Play services Library to run on client android phone. i want my app to run in much older android OS's(14,15,..) 
Problems:

1- Clients need to install or activate Play services app.

2- then Clients have to update play services app to the latest version to use my app with google maps.

3- how to make app to run in older androids? just by specifying min sdk ?

so in order to solve first and third problem i've no idea but for the second one : 
building project with older Play service dependencies may help but i dont know how to do this or even it helps or not.

it'll appreciate if guys offer any solutions !
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What are the recommended practices for maintaining the widest backwards compatibility of an Android app while depending on Google Play Services?**

Here are the pointers I was able to aggregate concerning backwards compatibility, including those that use Google Play Services.

1. The Google Maps Android API [uses OpenGL ES version 2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#specify_android_permissions) to render the map. The least Android API version that has support for this is [API 8 or Android 2.2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) .
2. Compile against the oldest version of Google Play Services that contains the APIs that you need. As further discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810760/maximizing-google-play-services-backwards-compatibility), refrain from using wildcards like 5.+ because that updates to the latest play services. Instead use a widely used version like com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89.
3. [Use the V4 support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/09/google-play-services-81-and-android-60.html) to verify and request permissions.

com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1

You might also check some additional insight from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024040/minimal-android-api-level-to-run-google-maps-android-api-v2).