# How to check backward compatibility of google play services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a version of google play services 10.x. in my project. My emulator has a version of 9.x. I wish to make my project backward compatible, not just for my own device but for all other devices. What should be the lowest version of google play services that I can keep to make it so. I understand that this has to be officially stated in docs somewhere but I am unable to find it. I check the google docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Comment: You might want to check answer in this so [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410963/google-play-services-forward-and-backward-compatibility), there are no specific documents regarding checking of backward compatibility of Google Play Services. You can always check the [release note](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) for any news about what are excluded and included in the Google Play Service version. Also from another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25811536/5995040) to check on how to maximizing Google Play Services backwards compatibility. Hope this helps.